# Skype integration error with Node -[TypeError: Cannot read property 'logger' of undefined]

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-bots

I'm using the skype client for bot application. 
As soon as the server received the first message, an (internal) error was found on the server log.

Example code

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var calling = require('botbuilder-calling');

//=========================================================
// Bot Setup
//=========================================================

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
var chatConnector = new builder.ChatConnector({
     appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var chatBot = new builder.UniversalBot(chatConnector);
server.post('/api/messages', chatConnector.listen());

// Create calling bot
var connector = new calling.CallConnector({
    callbackUrl: 'https://<your host>/api/calls',
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var callingBot = new calling.UniversalCallBot(connector);
server.post('/api/calls', connector.listen());

//=========================================================
// Chat Dialogs
//=========================================================
// Add root dialog
chatBot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send('Hi... Please call me to interact with me.'); 
});

callingBot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send('Watson... come here!');
});;
```

When I run this node file

```
node app.js
```

Expected Behavior

What you expected to happen.
I expect skype client would receive a response from the chatbot and  callingBot

Actual Results

The following error occured

```
/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'logger' of undefined
    at UniversalBot.Library.findActiveDialogRoutes (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:135:20)
    at /home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:243:31
    at /home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:13
    at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
    at _parallel (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:9)
    at Object.async.parallel (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:731:9)
    at /home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:241:23
    at UniversalBot.Library.recognize (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:68:13)
    at UniversalBot.Library.defaultFindRoutes (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:236:14)
    at UniversalBot.Library.findRoutes (/home/marcus/advbot/node_modules/botbuilder/lib/bots/Library.js:85:18)
marcus@AppBuilderBot:~/advbot/calling$ A
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue adding

```
bot.use(builder.Middleware.dialogVersion({ version: 1.0, resetCommand: /^reset/i }));
```

as I've read in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2846

Comment: I was already using this line of code in my file but no luck and skype and FB client is giving same error for my ABC account but its working with another account.